# How to break out of Next/React import hell?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

After using Vue and Nuxt for more than a year, I decided to learn React and Next.js and almost immediately noticed the horrible Developer Experience.

Every stylesheet and component needs to be imported so there's always bloated import hell at the start of each component.

Not to mention if you need an extra library as you can't hook into any global object like Nuxt's `this.$plugin` option.

Is there some package to manage these imports for Nextjs? As far as I know, everyone who uses it doesn't mind it and that's what surprises me.

This Question may come as an insult to React and it is, but I just want at least one reason to join the hype-train as to why React is more popular.

Comment: for NextJS just once import React in _document.js and doesn't required that import it in any component

Comment: But components (buttons) in other components?
Is there a way to import them automatically? In Nuxt, you just write the component name and it does everything for you,

Answer (score 0):

create a file in *pages* directory named it `_doucument.js` or `_document.ts` (for TypeScript) and import React in it like below :
(below codes are TypeScript)

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, {
    DocumentContext,
    Head,
    Html,
    Main,
    NextScript,
} from 'next/document';


export default class CustomDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
        return { ...initialProps };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <title>Your title</title>
                </Head>
                <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}
```

and any more doesn't require that import React in any components.

Comment: But Import React in components is not needed anyway.
The question isn't about Import "React", but instead of importing a library and components every time you use them.
I can't even remember, how many times I've written `import Button from 'components/button`. It's just a damn chore and Nuxt provides auto-component import.
Why isn't this already a thing in react??